# Is anyone watching us?

Tags: belief, atma

Is there any eye who is watching us continuously and keeping record of our what we did?

I want to know about any written thing in Vedas and any story about this.

Comment: Nothing in the Vedas. Your own soul records it all.

Comment: Ofcourse God is watching everything that you do and God knows all. God is ever-present everywhere. God is omnipresent, therefore He is Here Right Now sir!! All the best

Answer (score 3):

There are as many answers to this question as there are different schools in Hindu philosophy. I'll cite a few of them,

### Rgveda

> ### [Nasadiya Sukta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasadiya_Sukta)
>
> को अद्धा वेद क इह प्र वोचत्कुत आजाता कुत इयं विसृष्टिः ।
>
> अर्वाग्देवा अस्य विसर्जनेनाथा को वेद यत आबभूव ॥६॥
>
> But, after all, who knows, and who can say Whence it all came, and how
>   creation happened? the gods themselves are later than creation, so who
>   knows truly whence it has arisen?
>
> इयं विसृष्टिर्यत आबभूव यदि वा दधे यदि वा न ।
>
> यो अस्याध्यक्षः परमे व्योमन्त्सो अङ्ग वेद यदि वा न वेद ॥७॥
>
> Whence all creation had its origin, he, whether he fashioned it or
>   whether he did not, he, who surveys it all from highest heaven, he
>   knows - or maybe even he does not know.

Clear indication of acceptance of the unknown including accepting the ignorance of what happens with your own *karma*.

### [Srimad Bhagavatam](http://vedabase.com/sb/4/21/27/en2)

> अस्ति यज्ञ-पतिर् नाम | केषाञ्चिद् अर्ह-सत्तमाः ||
>
> इहामुत्र च लक्ष्यन्ते | ज्योत्स्नावत्यः क्वचिद् भुवः ||  4.21.27
>
> My dear respectable ladies and gentlemen, according to the
>   authoritative statements of śāstra, there must be a supreme authority
>   who is able to award the respective benefits of our present
>   activities. Otherwise, why should there be persons who are unusually
>   beautiful and powerful both in this life and in the life after death?

Clear indication of a tradition where your conscious actions are taken very seriously.

## Adi Shankara in his bhashya on the Brahma sutras

[4.1.13-15](http://www.advaita-vedanta.org/archives/advaita-l/2010-August/025268.html)

> both the past sins and merits as well as future sins and merits will be destroyed by *jnana*. The karma, both good and bad, that is accumulated from the past but that has not yet begun to yield results is also called *sanchita karma*. The karma, both good and bad, of the present life, that will yield results in the future is called *agami karma*.

Pointing a tradition where papa and punya dictates your future but without any intervention by God, rather through karma and can be overcome through jnana.

Answer (score 2):

You are watching yourself. Forget God etc. you always know what you are doing and always try to be a good human being... Not for God or for anyone... Be a good human being for yourself.

However, according to the Vedas etc. Yama tracks all of your sins and the good things you did. After death you will get rewarded for your good deeds and punished for your sins (read the Bhagavad Gita for the types of sins you get for types of mistakes). And then you get reincarnated again... Unles you were a very good human being, then you get moksha (you become a part of god and get real eased from the cycle of rebirth and death).

Comment: You should cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

You yourself, are watching yourself. This is explained in Ashtavakra Geeta

> Righteousness and unrighteousness, pleasure and pain are purely of the
>   mind and are no concern of yours. You are neither the doer nor the
>   reaper of the consequences, so you are always free. 1.6
>
> **You are the one witness of everything and are always completely free.**
>   **The cause of your bondage is that you see the witness as something
>   other than this.** 1.7
>
> The body, heaven and hell, bondage and liberation, and fear too, all
>   this is pure imagination. What is there left to do for me whose very
>   nature is consciousness? 2.20

One true non-dual consciousness, is real self, pervading everything like space and watching a foolish play, called universe.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, I do not have a way to quote the reference for this. However those who can, please edit.

When Shakuntala comes to king Dhushyant with their son Bharath, Dhushyant rejects her claims. During that process, she goes on to great length explaining the atman and sareera concepts and in that process she quotes a list of 25 people who always watches all. Unfortunately the discourse presenter did not go in depth on who these 25 people are and hence I am unable to mention here.

Comment: Do you have any details as to who the presenter was and what discourse it was?

Comment: It is by Sri. Velukudi Krishnan on Mahabaratha series. In the discourse he clearly says the count as 25 but unfortunately before answering the topic got deviated and it was never taken up further.  I will try to hear again and find the exact position.